# Turning the legend box off makes the legend title disappear in Matlab

Tags: matlab

When I turn the legend `box off`, the legend title disappears. What am I doing wrong?

```
hL = legend ((h([1 2])), {'North', 'South'});
set(hL,'box','off')
newPosition = [0.83 0.8 0.1 0.1];
newUnits = 'normalized';
set(hL,'Position', newPosition,'Units', newUnits);
v = get(hL,'title');
set(v,'string','Region','fontsize',9);
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm unsure what you mean - would you mind explaining? Thanks

Comment: What is h([1 2])?  Can you just make your plot and then call legend like this: hL = legend('North', 'South');  The command: set(hL,'box','off') worked fine for me.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion - I should have mentioned that in my plot, I actually use h([2 1]). I'm plotting h = bar(x,y,'stacked') where y contains two columns of 'south' and 'north' data (north bars appearing on the top of the south bars). Because my yData is ordered that way, the legend list default is 'South', 'North'. Sorry, I should have explained but didn't actually think this would affect it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok now I understand your problem.

I made up some data:

```
n = 8;
x = [1:n];
y(:,1) = rand(1,n);
y(:,2) = rand(1,n);
```

Then used your plotting commands:

```
h = bar(x,y,'stacked');
hL = legend ((h([1 2])), {'North', 'South'});
```

But rather than turn off the box, just set the edge color to white:

```
set(hL, 'EdgeColor', 'w')
```

And then using:

```
newPosition = [0.75 0.75 0.1 0.1];
newUnits = 'normalized';
set(hL,'Position', newPosition,'Units', newUnits);
v = get(hL,'title');
set(v,'string','Region','fontsize',9);
```

I get:

[image]

So now the "Region" title doesn't disappear.

Note that I had to change the coordinates of the legend to keep it within the figure, but of course you can place that where you want.

Comment: Thanks - I didn't actually think of just making the box edgecolour white!